How to remove duplicate in the same row
I have a table with column columna with data in the same row:
columna
-----------------
a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b

I tried this, but it's not good
duplicated_rows AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columna) AS row_num
    FROM 
        tablea
)
SELECT * 
FROM duplicated_rows
WHERE row_num > 1;

Not sure how to remove duplicate so I will get result
columna
-------
a,b


got error. Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions.

Huh, do you mean you have a single row with comma separated column value? That might be the issue, don't store multiple items in one column

select distinct val from tablea cross apply (select string_split(a)) v

@shawnt00 got error  'string_split' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

select distinct value from tablea cross apply string_split(columna, ',') v Sorry. I'm not advocating for storing data this way of course.

Actually, looking at your attempt are you sure you don't just need select distinct columna from tablea?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.
Notable points:

CROSS APPLY convert column value into XML.
XQuery distinct-values() function does the magic.

SQL
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b'),
('cat,dog,cat');

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.*, c
   , REPLACE(c.query('distinct-values(/root/r)').value('.','VARCHAR(1000)'), SPACE(1), @separator) AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



id
tokens
result




1
a,b,a,b,a,b,a,b
a,b


2
cat,dog,cat
cat,dog



